Why Rama says Sita to set her mind on Lakshmana/Bharata
Namaste,
I am reading Ramayana from Orignal source in Kannada. After all war has been over, when Sita comes near to Rama, Rama starts banishing Sita mentioning various things like doubtful character etc. Which is not premise of my question, but one thing which I have doubt on these two shlokas:

adadya vyāhṛtaṃ bhadre mayaitat kṛtabuddhinā |
lakṣmaṇe vātha bharate kuru buddhiṃ yathāsukham || 6-115-22

Meaning:

"O gracious lady! Therefore, this has been spoken by me today, with a resolved mind. Set you mind on Lakshmana or Bharata, as per your ease."

And next Shloka:

śatrughne vātha sugrīve rākṣase vā vibhīṣaṇe |
niveśaya manaḥ sīte yathā vā sukhamātmanaḥ || 6-115-23

Meaning:

"O Seetha! Otherwise, set your mind either on Shatrughna or on Sugreeva or on Vibhishana the demon; or according to your own comfort."

As you can see Rama clearly taunts Sita saying set your mind on Lakshmana/Bharata/Shatrughna/Sugreeva or Vibhishana! Why did Rama say this? Doubting character is some what understandable saying she was in someone else's house. But being such a lovable husband why he has to say Sita to set her mind on another men? Any expert opinion on this?
I am just asking this to get clarified, no where I am disrespecting Shri Rama, I think Rama wouldn't have been said this without valid reason?
